# Handling circular imports in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

//x.js

```
const {function1}=require('./y');    
const function2=()=>{
 console.log('from function 2 ');
 function1()
}
function2();

module.exports={function2}
```

//y.js

```
const {function2}=require('./x');


const function1=()=>{
 console.log('hello from function1');
 function2();
}

module.exports={function1};
```

The function2 in y.js doesn't execute when I run the x.js file and a type error is thrown which says that function2 is not function.

```
node testing/x.js 
from function 2 
hello from function1
/media/xyz/9A2A71AB2A718553/abc/ghf/testing/y.js:6
 function2();
 ^

TypeError: function2 is not a function
   at function1 (/media/xyz/9A2A71AB2A718553/abc/ghf/testing/y.js:6:3)
   at function2 (/media/xyz/9A2A71AB2A718553/abc/ghf/testing/x.js:5:3)
   at Object.<anonymous> (/media/xyz/9A2A71AB2A718553/abc/ghf/testing/x.js:7:1)
   at Module._compile (module.js:649:30)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:660:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
   at tryModuleLoad (module.js:501:12)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:493:3)
   at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:690:10)
   at startup (bootstrap_node.js:194:16)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how much you know about modules in general, but you might find [this answer of mine on SoftwareEngineering.SE helpful](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/200652/51295). When you do `require('./x')` inside `y.js`, you get the *in progress, partially-built* `exports` object from the `x` module. At the time `x` requires `y`, `x` hasn't yet added `function2` to its exports object, and it won't do so until its call to `require('./y')` finished and it can execute the final line in `x.js`.

In other words, repeated calls for `require('foo')` don't re-run the code in module `foo`. Instead, they produce the one-and-only `module.exports` that has already been created for `foo`. Even if `foo` has not yet run to completion, the module has an incomplete `module.exports` object that was created when it was first `require`d.

The trick here is not to overwrite the `module.exports` object, but simply add methods to it.

x.js

```
const {function1}=require('./y');    
const function2=()=>{
 console.log('from function 2 ');
 function1()
}

module.exports.function2 = function2;

function2();
```

y.js

```
const xModule = require('./x');

const function1=()=>{
 console.log('hello from function1');
 xModule.function2();
}

module.exports={function1};
```

By doing `xModule = require('./x')` and `xModule.function2()` in `y.js`, we allow `function1` to wait until the `x` module has defined `function2` and added it to its `module.exports` object.

We also have to move the call to `function2()`  inside `x.js` to below the creation of `module.exports.function2`, since a call to `function2` will cause a call to `function1`, which expects the `x` module to have its `function2` method on `module.exports` already.